# How to check mysql password change and other events logs

Tags: mysql, php, windows-server

Recently someone change my phpmyadmin password and drop database

I think it was sql injecting.

Now I want to find information about this like when, how and who change my password

Please tell me where I can find my mysql v 5.5 logs (Windows Server 2012)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

by default MySQL community version not support audit

You have only one build in way - enable general log for log all activity on MySQL server

alternatives for enterprise version - https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/management/audit_log_plugin.html

MariaDB audit plugin You can install and on Linux and on Windows server - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-the-mariadb-audit-plugin/

Comment: ups - date too old :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends.
Did you even enable and set log files for MySql ?

You should check information on: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-logs.html

if it is already enabled, go to your mysql directory. Some default location:

```
 mysql/data/mysql.log
```

Comment: I didn't enabled them